# Why do some DataMember attributes have brackets while others have not?

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer

The MSDN documentation about the [DataMemberAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class shows a example below.

Sometimes brackets are set and sometimes are not. What is the reason behind?

Example:

```
[DataMember()]
    public string FirstName;

 [DataMember]
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return LastNameValue; }
        set { LastNameValue = value; }
    }
```

Comment: No difference, they are equal

Comment: The parens can be used since sometimes there will be parameters that go to the Attribute's constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a C# syntax issue. It has nothing to do with these particular classes.

Brackets are optional for attributes if you do not pass arguments to the constructor of the attribute.

I recommend that you decide which style you like and stick to it.